# Delete identical reports having similar information

Tags: compare, report, word-contentcontrol

We have more then 2000 report in my company and these reportes are created by different-2 team for different use case. There are multiple reports created by different-2 team and these reports have commom information but format is different. Is there any why to identify common report using any software or any manual approach. I need to delete common report .

Moreover there are some report  having 80% or 70% similar information and we needs to identify and club these report to reduce the count.

I need to identify a approach to find common report but dont know how to get it. I am not familier with these reports so don't knwo the common report as well

Comment: This query is related to report Rationalization. I want to know hoe to rationaliz report and what are the tools to perform the same. Do we have any open source available in market to rationalize report.